# 404 error, Jersey 2.x on tomcat 8

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm working on my first RESTful Api with `Jersey 2.x` and `tomcat 8` but when I try to acceed to my Resources I keep getting a 404 errors.

this is my **web.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.pj.api.application.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.pj.api.application.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My **Application** class :

```
@ApplicationPath ("api")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application () {
        packages ("com.pj.api.resources");
    }   
}
```

My **Resources** class :

```
@Path ("value=/users")
public class UserResources extends ResourcesImpl {

    private UserDao user = new UserDao ();

    @Override
    public List<Data> getList () {
        return user.getList ();
    }

    @GET
    @Path ("value=/test")
    public String Test () {
        return "{'a':'hey'}";
    }

    @Override
    public Data get (String id) {
        return user.get (id);
    }

    @Override
    public void post (Data data) {
        user.post (data);
    }

    @Override
    public void put (Data data) {
        user.put (data);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Data data) {
        user.delete (data);
    }
}
```

When deploying the project on Tomcat, and acceeding to the Service through the URL : `http://localhost:8080/PJ/api/users/test` it gives me a 404 error and `Cannot cast org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`

**p.s** : I do NOT use Maven

What could be the problem here ? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this is a classpath issue. How do you run it? do you deploy war file or within the IDE?

Comment: @fmucar, I'm running the project within eclipse

Comment: check your classpath and remove any servlet-api jar files from classpath

Answer (score 1):

This certainly looks like a  classpath issue. Does your server runtime include some default Jax-rs libraries?  I faced a similar issue when trying to deploy my app built on Jersey 2.4 on a server that included jax-rs 1.1 libraries,  so I had to rebuild my app on Jersey 1.18. Check your server runtime in Eclipse for any existing libraries

Answer (score 0):

Your app differs a lot from mine. I suggest you to take a look at a simple hello world example that you can find [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/).

As you can see a simple service is:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

         String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
         return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
 }
```

the **web.xml** should look like:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Web request from `projectURL/rest/hello/` will match to `HelloWorldService` through `@Path("/hello")`  and the `{any values}` from `projectURL/rest/hello/{any values}` will match to parameter annotated with `@PathParam`.

The URL is `http://localhost:8080/<your_project>/rest/hello/Mehdi`

You can use this base example as a root base and adapt it to your needs.

Hope to help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Jersey 2, and I've read that it's quite different from Jesrsey1

Comment: @Mehdi sorry, my bad. In that case you can take a look at [this example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.9/examples/helloworld-spring-annotations/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/hello/spring/annotations/annotations). If you want I can remove my answer