# Unable to get desired output for restful sample project

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, tomcat

I am new to Restful services. Tech stack used: Intellij IDE, Jersey, Maven, Tomcat. I have added the required dependencies in the project.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

When i deploy and run this project on tomcat. I get a blank page with url: http://localhost:8080

I appended hello to it: http://localhost:8080/hello - but still could see nothing in the browser.

Comment: since the question wasn't getting submitted, i edited it in html mode by adding <br> tags, kindly ignore the tags while reading the question.

Comment: You probably need to append your war module name before "hello"

Comment: Is this the only code you have? Check this question to compare what you have to what you should have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144289/404-error-jersey-2-x-on-tomcat-8

Comment: Try: http://localhost:8080/[PROJECT_NAME]/hello

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. i tried using the url - http://localhost:8080/RestC/rest/hello, where in RestC is my project name, it's giving 404 error. i referred a quite a number of links on stackoverflow and tried revisiting jars added, build path. still issue isnt getting fixed.

Comment: here is my web.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>RestC</display-name>

Comment: web.xml:   
    <display-name>RestC</display-name> <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>example</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>